# How to override application scopes with rolebased scopes from access token in identity server 4?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

1.Trying to implement role-based access control (RBAC) to replace existing scopes with role-based scopes in access tokens.

2.The application currently uses scopes "openid", "offline_access", and "managementapi:allowall" for authorization.

3.However, I want to replace these scopes with role-based scopes in access token. Specifically, the role associated with the user only has one scope, which is "managementapi:allowall".

Below is my code

```
context.IssuedClaims.RemoveAll(c => c.Type == "scope");
           foreach (var scope in roleMappedScopes)
           {
               if (allowedScopes.Contains(scope))
               {
                   claims.Add(new Claim("scope", scope));
              }
           }
           context.IssuedClaims = claims;
```

But in access token only application scopes are returning to scope claim.